# Handling Pagination - seems to be an endless loop?

Tags: python, api, pagination

I have the function below to handle pagination, but curious because the loop seems to never and and I don't think the volume of data is that large - not sure why the loop will not end?

```
def get_report(endtime, starttime, param_type):
    
    final_output = []
    
    with open('endtime.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(endtime)
    
    response = vrbl.authed_session.get(
        vrbl.api_url,
        params=param_type.update({'endTime': endtime, 'startTime': starttime}),)
    
    response = response.json()

    while response.get('nextPageToken') is not None:
        final_output.extend(response)
        
        token = response.get('nextPageToken')
        response = vrbl.authed_session.get(
         vrbl.api_url,
        params=param_type.update({'endTime': endtime, 'startTime': starttime, 'pageToken': token}),)
        print(response)
        response = response.json()
        
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write('example_report.json')
    
    #print(response)

get_report(vrbl.endtime, vrbl.starttime,vrbl.params)
```

Comment: Are you sure you use API in a correct way? Some pagination mechanism always returns `nextPageToken` but has something like boolean `more` that indicates is it end

Comment: this one does not return nextPageToken as a key value if there is in fact no next page

Comment: I am afraid your program works fine. There are other things that can blocks you like server problems (with no timeout you can wait forever for a response) or some DDOS protection. I could recommend to increase page size, but without knowing API it's hard to help more.

Comment: ok, so the only other best route would be to use concurrent threads https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

This would make it finish quicker?

Comment: Again, it depends - if API is created a way when you access next page by some `page_index` you can parallel that, but in your case it seems you need to get `nextPageToken` so cannot make next request before previous ends and concurrency won't help. Did you try to increase `page_size`?